# About declaring and initializing a structure in Fasm assembly

Tags: assembly, fasm

I've read the documentation of Fasm, but I can't figure out this. In Nasm I'd first declare a struct in ".bss" and then define it in ".data":

```
    section ".bss"

    struc my_struct
        .a resw 1
        .b resw 1
        .c resb 1
        .d resb 1
    endstruc

    section ".data"

    my_struct_var1 istruc my_struct
        at my_struct.a, dw 123
        at my_struct.b dw, 0x123
        at my_struct.c db, "fdsfds"
        at my_struct.d db 2222
    endstruc
```

**How can I do this in FASM exactly?**

```
; declaring

struct my_struct
    .a rw 1
    .b rw 1
    .c rb 1
    .d rb 1
ends

; or maybe this way?
; what's the difference between these 2?

struct my_struct
    .a dw ?
    .b dw ?
    .c db ?
    .d db ?
ends
```

1) Firstly, is that correct? Or should I use the macros "sturc { ... }" If so, how exactly?

2) Second, how can I initialize it in ".data"?

3) also there's a question in my code

Note it's an application for Linux 64

Comment: I would recommend the FASM mesage board https://board.flatassembler.net for a possibly better answer

Comment: I don't know nasm, but usually "rb/rw/rd" just "reserves" a byte/word/doubleword, not touching it at all (uninitialized). the same does "db ?/dw ?/dd ?". To initialize it, you have to use "db/dw/dd value", e.g. `dw 2000` (word with VALUE 2000) or `db 20` (byte 20). `rw 2000` would reserve a block of 2000 words

Comment: @Torito I'm not familliar with all assmblers, so I don't generalize. I can only assume it's the same for all ( most?) of them

Comment: @Tommylee2k, I think you're right (wrong?).

Answer (score 2):

The `struc` in FASM is almost the same as `macro`, only named with a label at the front.

The `struct` is actually a macro, that makes definitions easier.

If you are using FASM include files where `struct` macro is defined, following code will allow you to initialize structures:

```
; declaring (notice the missing dots in the field names!)

struct my_struct
    a dw ?
    b dw ?
    c db ?
    d db ?
ends

; using:

MyData my_struct 123, 123h, 1, 2
```

You can read more about FASM `struct` macro implementation in the [Windows programming headers](https://flatassembler.net/docs.php?article=win32#1.1) manual.

If you prefer to not use the FASM `struct` macro, you still can define initialized structures using the native FASM syntax, following way:

```
; definition (notice the dots in the field names!)

struc my_struct a, b, c, d {
    .a dw a
    .b dw b
    .c db c
    .d db d
}

; in order to be able to use the structure offsets in indirect addressing as in:
; mov  al, [esi+mystruct.c]

virtual at 0
  my_struct my_struct ?, ?, ?, ?
end virtual

; using:

MyData my_struct 1, 2, 3, 4
```